# Adding records into a database from an html form

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to add records into a database from a simple html form that I have created. I keep on getting this error:

> connected succesfullyError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

the connection is successful but something is wrong with the sql statement and I haven't been able to spot the error.

This is the form

```
 <form action="addplayer.php"method "post"/>

         <p> id: <input type="text" name="playerid"/></p>
         <p> Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></p>
         <p> Age: <input type="text" name="age"/></p>
         <p> Position: <input type="text" name="position"/></p>
         <p> Nationality: <input type="text" name="nationality"/></p>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

This is the connection

```
     <?php

define('DB_NAME', 'syokimaufc');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die ('could not connect: '. mysql_error());
}
$db_selected= mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected){
    die('can\'t use' . DB_NAME .': ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'connected successfully';
```

implementation

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';


$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'playerid');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age');
$position = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'position');
$nationality = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nationality');

$sql = "INSERT INTO players (playerid,Name,Age,Position,Nationslity) VALUES ('$id','$name','$age','$position',$nationality)";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around `$nationality` and your page is embarrassingly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Stop using mysql_* functions and do yourself a favor by learning to use prepared statements with PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (playerid,Name,Age,Position,Nationslity) VALUES ('$id','$name','$age','$position',$nationality)";
```

To:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (playerid,Name,Age,Position,Nationality) VALUES ('$id','$name','$age','$position','$nationality')";
```

**UPDATE**
As Jeff Puckett II correctly pointed out in the comment section below, I gave my initial answer hastily and should have mentioned that you're opening yourself up to SQL injection and other nasty problems by not sanitizing your data.

To do things more safely, change:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (playerid,Name,Age,Position,Nationslity) VALUES ('$id','$name','$age','$position',$nationality)";
```

To:

```
$_id = mysql_real_escape_string( $id );
$_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $name );
$_age = mysql_real_escape_string( $age );
$_position = mysql_real_escape_string( $position );
$_nationality = mysql_real_escape_string( $nationality );
$sql = "INSERT INTO players ( playerid, Name, Age, Position, Nationality ) VALUES ( '$_id', '$_name', '$_age', '$_position', '$_nationality' )";
```

Comment: Although not technically incorrect, this is a bad answer because it does not espouse best practices for sanitizing user input. You should try to post the best answer you can, not the fastest quickest dirtiest, and I believe you can do better :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am new to php and learning everyday. @JeffPuckettII i appreciate your comment but not the delivery.

Comment: hello again , i seem to have run into another slight problem. Once i run the code the webpage outputs "Completed successfully" but the record does not display. It seems like its entering null values for each of the fields because when i try to enter another record, i'm getting this error "connected successfully Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" How can i solve this?

Comment: @KevinG The best way to get the answer to your new question is to mark the correct answer to your initial question as the solution and then post the new question as an entirely new question.